# Why Is Youtube Video Not Filling UiWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I'm a noob to iphone development and I am having trouble displaying an embedded youtube video within a UIwebview.  Currently, the youtube video sits in the top left hand corner of the uiwebview and it also has an annoying border.  I set the youtube frame to the same dimensions as my uiwebview and the webview is set to "scale to fit".  How do I make my youtube content fit the entire screen and get rid of the border?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
NSString *video_ID = youtubeid;
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"320\" height=\"230\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",video_ID];
[videoScreen loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

EDIT

```
 NSString *video_ID = youtubeid;
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",video_ID];
[videoScreen loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: you're explicitly setting the width and height to 320x230. try 100%'s? or programmatically create the widget with javascript and get the web view's dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How/Where do I set dimensions to 100%

Comment: the inline iframe definition, where you specify `width=\"320\" height=\"230\"`

Comment: It didn't work.  Please check my edit.

Comment: ack; i need to play with it -- sorry. the latter suggestion might be better (programmatically creating it with JS), but obviously isn't as easy.

Comment: Have you tried aspect fill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have u tried this......

```
NSString *video_ID = youtubeid;
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",video_ID];
[videoScreen loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Note That %% is used for % character.

Comment: This is working for displaying at full width, but it is only displaying at half height (115).  Any thoughts?

Comment: scale to fit in uiwebview is used to scale the contains of web view according to the size of the web view..... just change the height of the web view 115 to 320 & see.....

Answer (score 0):

So first you must create a UIWebView and add it to your main view.
In the following I create a webview pointing to www.example.com where I have embedding the YouTube clip I want to play, I set it hidden because I'll later want to launch the video full screen.`

```
UIWebView *htmlView;
 htmlView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 55.0f, 105.0f, 369.0f, 178.0f) ];  
  [htmlView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];  
    htmlView.hidden = YES;  
     htmlView.delegate = self;  
      [self addSubview:htmlView];  
       [htmlView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"www.example,com"]]];  `
```

Answer (score 0):

So here I scan through all the buttons in the webview and select the first button found using the sendActionsForControlEvents function.

```
UIButton* findButtonInView(UIView* view)  
 {  
 UIButton *button = nil;  
  if( [view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]] )  
    {  
  return (UIButton*)view;  
   }  

    if( view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0 )  
    {  
    for( UIView *subview in view.subviews )  
    {  
    button = findButtonInView( subview );  
    if( button )   
    {  
      return button;  
  }  
   }  
    }  

     return button;  
      }  

    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView  
     {  
    UIButton *button = findButtonInView( webView );  
      if( button != nil )  
       {  
      [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
  }  
   }
```